# Drop table if exits not works on SQlite database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite Database on Database, I store that database from PHP Server, I crete database, If I add new values to PHP databse it's appear on my android device, but...

**MY PROBLEM**

When I delete one value to Server database, on my device not delete from sqlite database, database is not updated only when I delete values from php database but yes works when I add values...

**code DDBB**

```
public class BBDD extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

 String crear = "CREATE TABLE types(KEY_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                                            "value TEXT) ";


    public BBDD (Context contexto, String nombre, CursorFactory factory,
                 int version)
    {
        super(contexto, nombre, factory, version);
    }

    public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(crear);
    }

    public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnt, int versionNue)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS types");
        db.execSQL(crear);

    }
```

**Why not works `DROP TABLE IF EXITS`?**

Any suggestions?

**EDIT (ON ACTIVITY I CALL BBDD.JAVA)**

```
//declare
public BBDD types;
//.........

try
   {
                            JSONObject jresponse = new JSONObject(responseBody);

                            Map<String, String> types = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            Iterator<String> iterator = jresponse.keys();
                            while (iterator.hasNext())
                            {
                                String idType = iterator.next();
                                String nametype = (String) jresponse.get(idType);

                                tipos.put(idType, nametype );

                                //save on database
                                types = new BBDD(SplashScreen.this, "BBDD", null, 1);
                                SQLiteDatabase db= types.getWritableDatabase();

                                registro = new ContentValues();
                                registro.put("KEY_ID", idType);
                                registro.put("value", nametype );

                                if (db.insert("types", null, registro) != -1)
                                {

                                    db.close();
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                }
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: What has `onUpgrade` to do with anything that you have described? Show how you cal the `BBDD` constructor.

Comment: @Aspicas your question seems very unclear and also drop table only called when you create a new table which already exist. Please provide more information so I can help you :)

Comment: @Ajeet what information you need?

Comment: I want to know how your application informed about that a data from server has been deleted ?

Comment: @Ajeet only I create if not exits when I open my app again... check my updated question

Comment: I've no experience with this subject, but won't onUpgrade be called only if there's an alter on the original table ? Sounds like thoose 'hooks' are there  to manage the schema and not the content of the DB (But I may be totally wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** - It's `EXISTS`, not `EXITS`.
**2** - You are creating the table with the wrong id column name:

```
"CREATE TABLE types(KEY_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                                        "value TEXT) ";
```

You want this, instead:

```
"CREATE TABLE types(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                                        "value TEXT) ";`
```

**3** - To make the `onUpgrade()` method fire, you must `increase the value` of the **DATABASE_VERSION** constant

Comment: I don't know how I can increase `DATABASE_VERSION` with my code.. Can you help me?

Comment: You just change `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;` - By hand, not programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The `onUpgrade` call is used to manage the database schema when you release a new version of your app.
This has nothing to do with sychronizing data with a server.

If you need to update or delete rows, you have to do this manually by calling [update()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) or [delete()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29).